# How to invoke 'Sitecore Rocks' code generation?

Tags: code-generation, sitecore, sitecore-rocks

After installing Sitecore Rocks extension, I created a 'Sitecore > Code Generation > Template Classes' file to the project. I added my templates from Sitecore to the .scx file and tried running the file by selecting 'Run Custom Tool', but it doesn't seem to do anything. Is there something specific I need to do in order to run the code generation file and have it generate the classes for my Sitecore templates?

Thanks!

Comment: What specific plug-in to Sitecore Rocks did you add? I don't see those menu options myself.

Comment: We installed the latest 0.7.6 (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/44a26c88-83a7-46f6-903c-5c59bcd3d35b). If you right click on a folder in your project > Add > New Item > Visual C# > Sitecore > Code Generation > Template Classes file

Comment: I had some issues with code generation as well. After launching the "custom tool" you should see a designer.cs file with the code or with some error message in case something went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my finding on this,

Once you have setup Sitecore and Sitecore Rocks you can check the generated code file under the created file name as CodeGeneratedFile.Designer.cs (assuming the new file is named as 'CodeGeneratedFile')

The file should be type of 'Strongly Typed Items'

[image: Sitecore Rocks Code generation]

Based on this question I have written here in detail - [Code Generation using Sitecore Rocks](http://www.harshbaid.in/2013/09/23/code-generation-using-sitecore-rocks-and-visual-studio/)